# Is it possible to perform sequential row calculations in presto sql?

Tags: sql, bigdata, presto

I have user_cost information and hourly discount information.
I am trying to get the below result using below two tables.

The discount_per_time is applied every time of user_cost, and the users of the same time shares the discount.
Discounts are applied sequentially for each row, and are performed until no more discounts are available.

I thought it would be possible using presto's window function, so I tried it for a few days but couldn't do it. Can I create the below result through query?

table: user_cost

```
time    user_id     cost
1       aaa         20
1       bbb         5
2       aaa         11
2       bbb         5
3       aaa         15
4       aaa         1
4       bbb         1
```

table: discount_per_time

```
discount_id     cost
d-1             10
d-2             5
```

**RESULT:**

```
time    user_id     type        cost    discount_id     discounted_cost
1       aaa         discount            d-1             10
1       aaa         discount            d-2             5
1       aaa         usage       5                   
1       bbb         usage       5                   
2       aaa         discount            d-1             10
2       aaa         discount            d-2             1
2       bbb         discount            d-2             4
2       bbb         usage       1                   
3       aaa         discount            d-1             10
3       aaa         discount            d-2             5
4       aaa         discount            d-1             1
4       bbb         discount            d-1             1
```

+ add:

- You should be able to see which discounts apply to which users and how much per time.
- The discounted_cost per time cannot be greater than the usage cost and the discountable cost.
- If all of the cost of the time is discounted, "usage" is not displayed (instead, the value before discount can be inferred through discounted_cost).

e.g.

- User 'aaa' uses a cost of 20 and user 'bbb' uses a cost of 5 in a time.
  Both the 10 discount of d-1 and the 5 discount of d-2 are applied to aaa, so the final cost of aaa becomes 5. All discounts are applied to aaa, so the final cost of bbb is still 5.
- aaa uses 11 and bbb uses 5. d-1 gives aaa a discount of 10, d-2 gives a discount of 1 so aaa does not charge. 4 out of 5 of d-2 left. This can be applied to bbbs. So the final cost of bbb is 1.
- When both users' cost is 1, those are discounted by using only 2 out of 10 of d-1. There is no final usage for both users.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you upload a short runnable version of your code? This will make it easier for the community to help you.

Comment: you logic shown in sample output is not clear at all

Comment: @eshirvana I added a description of the condition. Thank you.